# Matlab 2d/3d figures into LaTeX

Tags: graphics, matlab

I'm writing a paper in LaTeX and want to include some figures from Matlab.

I have 2d plots and 3d surfaces to include.

1. Are there any guides to academic writing / published papers which show best practices of including Matlab-type figures? (Eg axis labeling, legends, angle of view for 3d surfaces)
2. What's the best way to port my Matlab figures into LaTeX that'll allow me flexibility with axes, angle of view, etc. I can export as PDF to get the job done, but it looks quite amateur.

Comment: I think the best way is to export the point data and include that in a tikz picture. Then you can control everything with latex (tikz).

Comment: `pgfplots` is what you need. Export point data and use `pgfplots` (its documentation is really good and contains also rules of thumb). I haven't used it in my thesis (time lacked to convert plenty of figures...) and I regret.

Comment: You can try matlab2tikz: https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz